# Running R script on hadoop and mapreduce

Tags: r, azure, hadoop, mapreduce, revolution-r

I have an R-script that does stuff with a bunch of tweets and I would like to use the same script on the same data but saved in an Hadoop file system. According to [this](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-revolution-r-enterprise-tutorial-hortonworks-sandbox/) Hortonworks tutorial I could use R code with data from my HDFS, but it is not quite clear.

Can I use the very same R-script, taking advantage of the mapreduce paradigm, by using this Revolution R? Should I change my code or is there a way to execute the same functions optimized for an Hadoop architecture?
My wish would be to write my code on a standard R IDE like R-Studio and then use it, or use the most of it, on my cloud services (such as Microsoft Azure) with mapreduce on the base.

Comment: We'd need to know more about your script - lots of text analysis is just splitting and counting, which is relatively easy to do in parallel, but others operations could be quite hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run any R script across different data platform from Hadoop to Spark to Teradata and SQL Server by using environment specific compute context.

Following two links should help you get started on how to use Revolution R /  Microsoft R Server on Hadoop:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/scaler-hadoop-getting-started

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-DataScience/blob/master/Misc/MicrosoftR/Samples/NYCTaxi/NYC2013_MRS_LinearBinary.Rmd